# I cannot run my R script in Xcode for OS X mavericks

Tags: r

I'm using Xcode for OS X mavericks. I have written the code in R and saved it as a script file (.r). I can't run the script directly in R, only in Xcode. However, I'm not sure how to run the script I saved in R in Xcode. Could someone offer a simple explanation? thanks

Comment: You have to run the R script in an R runtime environment. There are no R runtime environments or project targets for Xcode that I'm aware of.  Do you have R installed from http://www.r-project.org/ ?

Answer (score 0):

In the R runtime environment, type the following command and execute it:

```
source(file.path(path, filename.saved.from.xcode.ending.in.r))
```

Comment: or from a shell (terminal window) `R CMD BATCH filename.r`

Comment: Or you can use RScript